# What is the "star product" of vectors really called, and where can I learn more about it?

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, representation-theory, multilinear-algebra

Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ the idea is that the star product of $x$ and $y$ is the set of all possible dot-products of $x$ and $y$ as we permute one of these vectors while holding the other steady, with the added feature that each real number obtained in this way gets indexed by the permutation that produced it. Formally:

> **Definition.** Given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define that the *star-product* of $x$ and $y,$ written $x \star y$, is the formal $\mathbb{R}$-linear combination of permutations of $n$ given as follows. $$x \star y = \sum_{\pi \in S_n}(x \bullet (y \circ \pi)) \cdot \pi$$
>
> This defines a bilinear map $$\star : \mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[S_n]$$

For example:

$$(1,2) \star (3,4) = (1,2) \bullet (3,4) \pi_{(0)(1)}+(1,2) \bullet (4,3) \pi_{(0,1)} = 11\pi_{(0)(1)}+10\pi_{(0,1)}$$

My motivation for considering this thing is that the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) gives upper and lower bounds on the coefficients.

> **Question.** What is the "star product" of vectors really called, and where can I learn more about it?

Comment: This looks interesting. Unfortunately I don't think I have seen it anywhere else, but a few pointers that might help others: You can reformulate it (to maybe make it look more familiar to some people) so that instead of working with Von Neuman ordinals, what you are really doing is picking a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then there you are using the permutation representation of $S_n$ to define this product (which really just ends up in the real vector space with basis given by the permutations, rather than in the much larger free algebra generated by those permutations).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, perhaps its not always entirely clear, but I use the phrase "$R$-algebra freely generated by a monoid $M$" to mean $F(M)$, where $F$ is the left-adjoint of the forgetful functor $U:R\mathbf{Alg} \rightarrow \mathbf{Mon}.$ So basically, I use "freely generated" to mean "left-adjoint to the relevant forgetful functor."

Comment: Ahh, I see (but you still don't really use the algebra structure anywhere).

Comment: The standard notations for $\operatorname{Perm}\left(n\right)$ and $\operatorname{Alg}\left(n\right)$ are $S_n$ (or $\mathfrak{S}_n$) and $\mathbb R\left[S_n\right]$, respectively.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, thanks for the comment. I've replaced $\mathrm{Alg}(n)$ on this basis. As for $S_n$, I don't like it. Using a single letter for a global definition that's meant to be used mathematics-wide is usually a bad idea.

Comment: The only thing that comes immediately to mind is that this is a generalization of a circular cross-correlation. You can write the circular cross-correlation as the sequence of dot-products of $x$ and $y$ as you cyclically permute the elements of $y$.

Comment: If you remove all the categorical language you're just left with $x \star y = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \bigl( \sum_i x_i y_{\sigma(i)} \bigr) \sigma \in \mathbb{R}[S_n]$. Not sure why this would have a special name...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, what categorical language? von Neumann ordinals are a handy notational trick that comes from material set theory; they have nothing to do with category theory.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, also, note that your definition is more complicated than mine, because it fails to exploit the well-known dot product, whose basic properties are already well-understood. Other than that, our definitions are the same.

Comment: And also calling the symmetric group "the monoid (!) of all set-theoretic automorphisms of $n$", and the description of the group algebra... It's just obfuscation of simple concepts at this point. I hope you don't take this the wrong way, I'm just saying it's an obfuscated description of a simple sum...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, no, I like this viewpoint. There is a forgetful functor $\mathbb{R} \mathbf{Alg} \rightarrow \mathbf{Mon}$, and its left-adjoint turns a monoid $M$ into the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $R[M]$. On the other hand, there is no forgetful functor $\mathbb{R}\mathbf{Alg} \rightarrow \mathbf{Grp}$.

Comment: Isn't the "group Hopf algebra" functor left adjoint to the "grouplike elements" functor? I hope you see what I mean now: you can go very far down the rabbit hole, but in the end you're just describing something one learns about in undergrad...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, ummm... maybe. I don't know anything about Hopf algebras yet, unfortunately.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, sorry, I didn't mean to suggest we move the whole thing to chat. A reasonable formulation of these ideas would perhaps use inductive types to circumvent having to name the categories we're interested in and give a more "direct" definition of these kinds of syntactic constructions; but, since I don't know anything about inductive types, I prefer to use the language I'm familiar with. This isn't obfuscation; its me using the tools I'm comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you have $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ along with a group action of $S_{n}$ acting by permuting coefficients of your vectors (wrt lets say the standard basis). For each permutation $\pi$, you have a map $\varphi_{\pi}:\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\varphi_{\pi}:(x,y) \mapsto x \cdot y^{\pi}$ (each of these is actually a nondegenerate bilinear form).

Now you want to associate each $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ with an element of the regular $\mathbb{R}S_{n}$-module (or considered as a group algebra, depending on what you want to do with it) by
$$\star : (x,y) \mapsto \sum_{\pi \in S_{n}} \varphi_{\pi}(x,y)\pi.$$

For your actual question: "what is this map actually called?" Quite possibly, whatever you want to call it. I don't entirely know your motivation for looking at it; the fact that the coefficients are (sharply) bounded by the rearrangement inequality is trivial from the definition, as is the fact that there is a natural action of $S_{n}$ on $\mathbb{R}S_{n}$ fixing each element in the image of $\star$.  It is quite possible that there are some other interesting properties hiding in there, it could be fascinating to look at the geometry of this image set (though I'm guessing it is unlikely it has been considered before).